# How can i optimize this Firestore query?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am performing this query to get posts of user whom the current user follows [like in social media]. but this query is taking hell lot of a time.As you can see I also convert them to post entity and set their corresponding properties for each , I think that is the main culprit. How can i optimise it?

i have different current collection for both users and posts in firestore

```
suspend fun getPostsForProfile(uid: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        safeCall {
            Log.d(" basePostRepository ", " getPostsForProfile is called  ")
            val Currentuid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!
            // get Posts where authorUid is equal to uid
            val profilePosts = posts.whereEqualTo("authorUid", uid)
                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .get()
                .await()
                .toObjects(Post::class.java)
                .onEach { post ->
                    Log.d(" basepostRepository : getPostforProfile ", post.authorUid)
                    val user = getUser(post.authorUid).data!!
                    post.authorUsername = user.type
                    val  isLiked_init = post.likedBy.find { item -> item == Currentuid}
                    post.isLiked = when (isLiked_init) {
                        null -> false
                        else -> true
                    }
                }
            Resource.Success(profilePosts)
        }
    }


suspend fun getUser(uid: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        safeCall {
            val currentUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!
            val user = users.document(uid).get().await().toObject(User::class.java)
                ?: throw IllegalStateException()
            val currentUser = users.document(currentUid).get().await().toObject(User::class.java)
                ?: throw IllegalStateException()
            val  isfollowed_init = currentUser.follows.find { item -> item == uid}
            user.isfollowing = when (isfollowed_init) {
                null -> false
                else -> true
            }
            Resource.Success(user)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: I moved val user = getUser(post.authorUid) out of the loop as post.authorUid is always equal to uid. that helped. but in the getPostsforFollows() [code not uploaded here] i am getting no luck in optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you can do:

1 - when getting the data use the firestore `limit` to get onl a specific amount of posts. Idealy a little bit more than the user can se on a usual user device scrren size. Probably 15 to 20 and load more if the users scrolls. This is a good aproach for most queries where you know that there is a huge amount of data in it.

2 - save the author data to the post to avoid getting it by a separate call (even if it is a single user wou would make the same call again and again) also save the athor `uid`. That way you can query by the author `uid` the current user is following and awoid getting all posts and filtering them on the client side.

3 - don't call the users the current user is following each time you try to get the post author data/user. Save the followers in a collection and call them once with a realtime listener in your app.

Comment: i didn't get the third point. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can call the list of followers for a current user once and listen to changes to it in realtime. That way you would drasticaly reduce the amount of reads in your app. Imagine that one user has 500 followers. You would read all of them multiple times with your approach.